How to customize bibliography biber
I want to edit the way the bibliography is displayed:
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear, style=apa]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography/bib-4.bib};

This is the preamble and this is how its displayed:  Amara, U., Rittirsch, D., Flierl, M., & Brückner, U. (2008).
Interaction between the coagulation and complement system. Current topics in complement ii (pp. 68–76).; but I want to remove all the & and if there are more than 5 authors we should just add one author and 'et al'.

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Why did you tag your question with errors?

If you don't want the & then don't use apa style. The length of author lists can be controlled with maxnames and misnames. A quick overview can be found here: https://tug.ctan.org/info/biblatex-cheatsheet/biblatex-cheatsheet.pdf
